# PHP and HTML search engine customising

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to enable user sort how they want the search to be in other to ease searching, I'm looking for the right method to pass their option(sort) on to the server.

**Here is my html script**

```
<form action="searchresult.php" method="post" id="searchengine" >
    <div class="input-group" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 5px orange;border-radius: 20px">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button  class="btn  dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 35px;background-color:orange;color: white"><span class="fa fa-arrow-down"></span></button>
            <ul name="searchmethod" class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: orange;border:5px solid orange;margin-top: 10px;border-radius: 20px;padding:10px 5px;">
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><input type="button" readonly="" style="padding:2px 4px;margin:2px 6px;height:26px;background-color: gold;width:270px;border:0px" class="btn" value="Search By Reviewee's Name"></li>
                <li><input type="button" readonly="" style="padding:2px 4px;margin:5px 6px;height:26px;background-color: gold;width:270px" class="btn" value="Search By Reviewee's Website"></li>
                <li><input type="button" readonly="" style="padding:2px 4px;margin:2px 6px;height:26px;background-color: gold;width:270px" class="btn" value="Search By Reviewer's Name"></li>

                <li><input type="button" readonly="" style="padding:2px 4px;margin:2px 6px;height:26px;background-color: gold;width:270px" class="btn" value="Search By Review Date"></li>
                <hr>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="word" style="width:190px;height:35px;background-color: #f3f558;font-size: 13px;color: black;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;text-align:center;font-family: cursive;" maxlength="40" required="" id="word" placeholder="Start Searching..." pattern="[a-Z0-9.,\']+" >

        <span  class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn" style="height: 35px;background-color:orange;color: white"  type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </span>
    </div>

</form>
```

**and here is my php script**

```
<?php
//checks if the word and buttun are both available
if (!isset($_POST['word'])) {
    die('get outta here');
}
//catches the word and stored in variable word

$word = sanitizeString($_POST['word']);
$_SESSION['recentsearch'] = $word;
$length = strlen($word);
if ($length <= 5) {
    $newlength = ' ' . 'your search is too short, try a longer word ';
} elseif ($length > 5) {
    $newlength = "";
}

if (isset($_POST['searchmethod'])) {
    $searchMethod = $_POST['searchmethod'];
    switch ($searchMethod) {
        case "Search By Reviewee's Name":
            $title = "Reviewee's name";
            $searchMethod = 'reviewName';
            break;

        case "Search By Reviewee's Website":
            $searchMethod = 'reviewLink';
            $title = "Reviewee's Website Link ";
            break;
        case "Search By Reviewer's Name":
            $searchMethod = 'reviewBy';
            $title = "Reviewer's name ";
            break;
        case "Search By Review Date":
            $searchMethod = 'reviewDate';
            $title = "Review Date ";
            break;

        default:
            $searchMethod = 'reviewName';
            break;
    }
} elseif (!isset($_POST['searchmethod'])) {
    $searchMethod = 'reviewName';
    $title = "Reviewee's name";
}

$search_exploded = explode(" ", $word);
$x = 0;
foreach ($search_exploded as $search_each) {
    $x++;
    $construct = "";
    if ($x == 1) {
        $construct .="$searchMethod LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    } else {
        $construct .="AND $searchMethod LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    }
}
$construct = " SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE $construct ";


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $construct);

if (!$result->num_rows) {
    echo 'Oops! No result found For ' . $title . ' (' . $word . ')' . $newlength;
}
if ($result->num_rows) {
    $number = $result->num_rows;
    echo ' ' . $number . ' Results Found Relating to ' . $title . ' (' . $word . '), Click 
    Here To See Results';
}
?>
```

The problem is that the script does not recognize the option as post

Comment: One tip is to use a dropdown with radio buttons, and then pass them through a bunch of if(isset)s and do the good 'ol sorting method using your database

Comment: Using a `<select>` instead of a list will automatically send the selected option as a post value. If there is not a really good reason why you not already use select I would recommend you to use that.

Comment: ok i used a switch instaed of multiple ifelse